# Django py.test does not find settings module

Tags: python, django, pytest

I do have the following project structure

```
base
    __init.py
    settings
        __init__.py
        settings.py
    tests
        pytest.ini
        test_module.py
```

My `pytest.ini` looks like this:

```
[pytest]
#DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE =base.settings.settings
```

My `test_module.py` looks like this:

```
def test_django():
    from base.settings import settings as base_settings
    from django.conf import settings as django_settings
    assert 3==5
```

When I now run:

```
py.test
```

it will run the imports without issue and will raise an error at `assert 3==5` (as expected). This tells me that base is on `sys.path` and that `base.settings.settings` can be imported.

Now I change `test_module.py` to:

```
def test_django():
    from base.settings import settings as base_settings
    from django.conf import settings as django_settings
    print django_settings.xxx
    assert 3==5
```

When I now run:

```
py.test --ds=base.settings.settings
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: Could not import settings 'base.settings.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named base.settings.settings.

The same effect when I do not set the settings via command line, but via the `pytest.ini` file (by uncommenting the line).

It looks like I miss something here???

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because django.conf.settings is lazy it will attempt to import settings module only when you try to access it. That's why your test doesn't fail when you simply import settings object.

Your problem is already discussed here: https://github.com/pelme/pytest_django/issues/23

This is an issue with pytest and not with pytest-django itself. Pytest for some reason removes current directory from sys.path. It should be easy to work around it.

**Solution 1:**

```
PYTHONPATH=`pwd` py.test
```

**Solution 2:**

add this to your conftest.py (I assumed that conftest.py is in the same directory your apps are):

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

**Solution 3 (if you're using virtualenv wrapper):**

When you start a new project just add project's root directory to virtualenv's PYTHONPATH by
executing this line in your project's directory:

```
add2virtualenv .
```

Comment: py.test does not remove the current directory from sys.path, this is python's behaviour: when executing a script (py.test in this case) the directory of the script is added to sys.path.  When executing interactively the current working directory is added to sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuring_django.html#command-line-option-ds-settings), it seems that `base` is already in your path - so maybe you want to be using

```
py.test --ds=settings.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are there 3 "t" 's in your settings?
it should be settings as opposed to setttings

Comment: Thanks for catching the type. But unfortunately, this was not the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You run the second program without the `--ds=base.settings.settings` argument and not the first. This is where the error appears to be coming from.

Also when importing code of the same name `settings` I would be tempted to do something like:

```
from base.settings import settings as foo
from django.conf import settings as bar
```

Comment: I have incorporated your second recommendation. But I do not understand your first comment?

Comment: in the question you say "when I now run: `py.test`" but then the second time you say "When I now run: `py.test --ds=base.settings.settings`". Is this a typo? If not then the ds flag might be causing your problem

Comment: No this is not a typo, but exactly whant I wanted to show. I need to specify my settings somewhwere and for this example, I have choosen the ds flag. And as soon as I set this, I get the error message. In the first example, I only want to demonstrate that my settings are reachable via the python path. So on the one hand, my settings are on the python path. But on the other hand, as soon as I specify them, they cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. `pytest -s <project_dir>` works fine for me.